# How can I make my own Razor Helper method like @Html.TextBoxFor()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2, razorengine

I would like to implement something similar to @Html.TextBoxFor but instead called @Html.SwitchFor() to create a yes/no switch from a bool that I am using without having to add the extra html and classes each time.

Is there a way to do this with razor syntax?

Answer (score 1):

**You will probably have luck with this.**

Note that you should find yourself hovering over the **TextBoxFor** and clicking **F12** in **Visual Studio** and you will get the signature of the method that you are trying to imitate. That is a good place to start although it is a little bit hard to read if you don't take the time.

```
public static MvcHtmlString SwitchFor<TModel>(
   this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, 
           Object>> expression, Boolean wrap)
   {
        return wrap
            ? MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<div class='helloworld'>{0}</div>", 
              helper.TextAreaFor(expression))) : helper.TextAreaFor(expression);
   }
```

**Pass the Right Stuff**

You need to pass an **Expression** to the **TextBoxFor** extension. The method signature for the **m =>** is **Func** which passes your **TModel** (m)  to the function and returns an object.

**Do What You Want and Return the Default Implementation**

You can put anything in there. You can see that I just return the original method call passing the expression if the **wrap** is set to false.

**Make the Call**

All that is left to do is make the call as you had intended in the first place.

```
@(Html.SwitchFor(m => m.Data, true))
```

**Make it a Helper**

This is a little trickier than I first expected but it can be done, just add the following code into your **App_Code** folder in a **cshtml** file of your choice. Since you can't use **Generics** in helpers functions you have to create an actual function with the correct signature in an **@function { }** block.

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@functions
{
    public static HelperResult SwitchFor<TModel, Object>(HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, Object>> func, Boolean wrap)
    {
        var data = html.TextAreaFor(func);
        return WrapItUp(data);
    }
}
@helper WrapItUp(MvcHtmlString data)
{
    <div class="helloworld">
        @(data)
    </div>
}
```

**Make the Call, Well Almost**

You have to pass the HtmlHelper instance that is typed to your Model.

```
@(Html.SwitchFor(Html, m => m.Data, true))
```

By the way, 
This is great! It will help me out with laying out multicolumn forms in a more natural way. I am glad I came across your challenge since it is a solution I hadn't thought of myself.

Good Luck N Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

I found some help [Here](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/):

Some simple example code:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString SwitchSlider(this HtmlHelper helper, bool value)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("<div>html i want to output here</div>");
    }
}
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
@Html.SwitchSlider(true);
```

I am still unsure how to replicate something like TextBox *For* and passing in x => x.param